# YCSB error on Hbase

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I am trying to get YCSB-0.1.4 to test Hbase 0.98.1 on CDH 5.1.2. I followed instructions here https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Getting-Started.  When I run the YCSB test, it works but its not loading data into the usertable. Do not see any errors in log files.see command below and the operations are zero. How to fix ?

```
$  bin/ycsb load hbase -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=f1 -s | tee -a workloada.dat
YCSB Client 0.1
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=f1 -s -load
Loading workload...
Starting test.
 0 sec: 0 operations;
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.2-1031432, built on 11/05/2010 05:32 GMT

14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=sapphire
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_65
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_65/jre
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/voldemort-binding/conf:/home/YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/core/lib/core-0.1.4.jar:/home/YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/gemfire-binding/conf:/home/ /YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/nosqldb-binding/conf:/home/ /YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/jdbc-binding/conf:/home/ /YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/hbase-binding/lib/hbase-binding-0.1.4.jar:/home/ /YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/hbase-binding/conf:/home/ /YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4/infinispan-binding/conf
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/opt/oracle/bd_cell12.1.2.0.99_LINUX.X64_140907.2307/cellsrv/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.39-400.215.9.el6uek.x86_64
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=dodo
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hbase
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/ /YCSB/ycsb-0.1.4
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=zk:2181,zk1:2181,zk2:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=hconnection
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zk1/192.168.27.63:2181
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to zk1/192.168.27.63:2181, initiating session
14/09/23 10:11:12 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server zk1/192.168.27.63:2181, sessionid = 0x2488ae01865289b, negotiated timeout = 60000
 10 sec: 0 operations;
 20 sec: 0 operations;
 30 sec: 0 operations;
 40 sec: 0 operations;
 50 sec: 0 operations;
 60 sec: 0 operations;
 70 sec: 0 operations;
```

Comment: were you able to fix it? I'm facing same issue :|

Comment: Have you fixed your problem because i am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this error, i was working on `MultiNode` cluster (roughly 12-16) and this is what i had to change :-

1) Check if your HBase version in `YCSB\pom.xml` under `hbase10\hbase098\hbase094` is compatible with HBase version in your Single Node or Multi Node cluster. (look for `hbase10.version` )

2) Also provide HBase Configuration file path with ycsb command .
ex. 
This is your command :- `bin/ycsb load hbase -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=f1 -s`

It should be like this :- `bin/ycsb load hbase -P workloads/workloada -cp $HBase_HOME/conf/-p columnfamily=f1 -s`

**FYI** :- I have not provided configuration file path when i tried with single node cluster and it worked. But with Multi Node cluster i had to give configuration file path.

There is one more thing to look for , `usertable` should have column family with name `f1` (Default is `family` in `workload` configuration file)

Hope It helps. :)